# I am appearing certification SP 14 on August 5th, 2014. When release exam will be application to me?

Tags: certification, release

I am appearing certification SP 14 on August 5th, 2014. When release exam will be application to me and up to which date I have to pass the release exam?

I am not clear about concept of Release exam.

Thanks in advance.
Manish

Answer (score 2):

You'll be taking an exam on the summer release version of salesforce. **That means that you'll have to do release exams for every release after the realease on which you take the exam (summer)**. So, you'll have to take release exames as soon as winter '15  (which is at the end of 2014).

**For every new release salesforce provides release notes  and release training, these are freely available and usually accessible before a new release.** Release exams for a release, usually become available within a few weeks after a new release.

Comment: What does SP mean?  I understand WI indicates Winter.  S for Summer. but SP?

Comment: Spring, but that's probably not an official abbriviation